# Using the PowerShell call (&) operator to call PowerShell scripts with switch parameters

Tags: powershell

Suppose we have the following `SwitchTest.ps` script

```
param(
    [switch]$Flag = $false
)

echo "Flag: $Flag"
```

The following works as expected:

```
& ".\SwitchTest.ps1" -Flag
Flag: True
```

However this doesn't

```
& ".\SwitchTest.ps1" "-Flag"
Flag: False
```

Furthermore, if we modify `SwitchTest.ps` to look like this:

```
param(
    [switch]$Flag = $false,
    [string]$Str = $null
)

echo "Flag: $Flag"
echo "Str: $Str"
```

We get this expected behavior:

```
& ".\SwitchTest.ps1" -Flag
Flag: True
Str:
```

And this unexpected one:

```
& ".\SwitchTest.ps1" "-Flag"
Flag: False
Str: -Flag
```

I tried `-Flag true`, `-Flag $true`, `-Flag:$true`... no cigar. It looks like the switch param is "skipped" when quoted (i.e. when it's a proper string) - why? What do I do if I want to build `"-Flag"` programmatically?

Comment: A string is always a string...... If you want to execute a command stored in a string, use `iex` as @briantist suggested.

Comment: See if this article helps clear it up: [Running Executables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell).

Comment: I feel like this sentence from the docs is what you don't want to here: _Because the call operator does not parse the command, it cannot interpret command parameters._ I am inclined to side with Briantist. This is not what it is for. Why use the call operator when you should just be able to omit it when calling a script (testing just in case)?

Comment: What if it was a scriptblock, though.  Don't you need to use the call operator then?

Comment: I understand my mistake now. I was trying to invoke a PS construct using plain strings (I wrongly assumed all parameters boiled down to strings). I needed a PS mechanism for a PS construct (in this case, splatting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgive me if I am off-base, but if you want to have that flag conditionally set, drop the call operator and just use splatting.

```
PS M:\Scripts> $params = @{Flag=$true;Str="Bagels"}

PS M:\Scripts> .\switchTest.ps1 @params
Flag: True
Str: Bagels
```

Comment: Beautiful, splatting works even with the call operator (which I like to keep so I have consistent code whether I'm calling a PS script or a "normal" exe).

Answer (score 4):

Your asking a very good question and have set up a very good test case. Let's leave flag without a parameter so it defaults to $Null.  When you specify `-Flag` by itself, PowerShell uses the switch paramater. But, PowerShell interprets `"-Flag"` as a string and therefore tries to find a parameter that matches a string variable and passes that string (including the `-` because it is in double quotes) to the parameter that matches `[String]` type. Lastly, since you sent a string `"-Flag"` to the string variable, the `Flag` variable was left to its default value which was `$Null` or `$False`. Nice question.

Here's your code you can use to test this out.

```
#Put this in a script file, e.g. ParamTest.ps1
Flag: False
Str: -Flag

param(
    [switch]$Flag,
    [string]$Str = $null
)

Write-Output "Flag: $Flag"
Write-Output "Str: $Str"
```

Execute just as you did above:

```
 & ".\SwitchTest.ps1" "-Flag"
```

But now that you see how PowerShell assigns passed in parameters, try the following to trigger the `Flag` parameter as you intended were originally intending to do:

```
& .\ParamScript.ps1 "-Flag" -Flag
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're seeing is exactly what I would expect.

If you want to build it programmatically, use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849893.aspx).

Comment: I know `iex` works, I'm asking why `&` doesn't and if there's any workaround.